# Аналог form.Show(); в WPF?

Tags: wpf

Привет. Есть ли какой-то аналог form.Show(); для WPF? Создал страницу которую нужно показать как отдельное окно. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: `MyWindow.Show();` читать [здесь](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/20.2.php)

Comment: Спасибо. Создал не window, а page, поэтому Show() не увидел.

Comment: `Page` используют для отображения во фрейме или просто в `ContentControl.Context = new MyPage();`

Comment: @Bulson, ответы в ответы